# conversion from char * to uint8_t *

Tags: c

I am a bit at a loss as to why the compiler doesn't throw any kind of warning.

```
int32_t CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int32_t nCmdShow)
{
  //..
}
```

Above is my Windows specific main function. Note that `lpCmdLine` parameter has type `LPSTR` which a `typedef` for a `char *`.

Now, I have defined a function with the following prototype:

```
void COM_ParseCmdLine(uint8_t *lpCmdLine);
```

When I pass my `lpCmdLine` variable into this function, it operates as expected and gives the correct results, because command line characters are 8 bits and positive in decimal value.

However, I am somewhat surprised that the compiler doesn't warn against the fact that we are potentially losing the sign if we deference a `uint8_t *` vs a `char *`.

Comment: signedness of `char` is implementation defined. It's not guaranteed to be signed, anyway.

Comment: Have you turned on warnings from the compiler?

Comment: Try with `void COM_ParseCmdLine(signed char *lpCmdLine)`. If there is warning, the problem is in compiler setting (set to unsigned).

Comment: @SelçukCihan You were right. VS2015 default warning level wasn't high enough. After setting `/Wall` compilation mode, sure enough the warning popped up. It seems like a serious enough warning to be presented without having to change the warning level...
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Don't edit title like that. Ask @i486 to post an answer (or post it yourself) and mark it as accepted (see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) )

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link Thomas.

Comment: @madski: Opinions differ on warnings. Some (like you, and me) consider this an issue. Others say "you don't lose *bits*, that's all that counts, and warnings are a nuisance, I know what I'm doing". Interestingly enough, the definition of GCC's `-Wall` currently stands at "all the warnings [...] *that are easy to avoid*", which is a long shot from "**all** warnings", something that still catches people unawares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `char` type has implementation-defined signedness, meaning that it can be equal to either `signed int` or `unsigned int`, from compiler to compiler.

Therefore it is quite possible that `uint8_t` is 100% compatible with `char` on your specific system and then you won't get any warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the compilation warning level to `/Wall` will produce the mentioned warnings.

Comment: ...for your specific compiler. GCC is a bit dumb, because it still gives this warning even if you set `-funsigned-char`.